# Start process if dead

Tags: linux, bash, process, daemon

What I'm trying to do is to start a process if not started. Here is what I try

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`ps ax | grep app | grep -v grep | wc -l`
  if [ $pid = 0 ]
then
 /etc/init.d/app start
fi
```

The problem is that the line

```
/etc/init.d/app start
```

is not executed. What is wrong here ?
I know that I can you daemontools but I like the "bash" approach.

Comment: Have you tried running the `ps ax ...` line by itself to see what it returns?

Comment: `pid` is usually a process ID. In this case, it's a count.  That's dangerous, because anything can put names into the process table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `==` operator.

Best may be something like

```
pid=`ps ax | grep app | grep -v grep`
test -z "$pid" && /etc/init.d/app start
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the double grep by turning your keyword into a regex that doesn't match itself.  And you can use `grep -c` instead of counting with `wc`. In your script, you could try:

```
pcount=`ps ax | grep -c "[a]pp"`
```

Alternately, use the actual pid instead of the process count:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=`ps ax | awk '/[a]pp/{print $1}'`

if ! ps "$pid" >/dev/null; then
  /etc/init.d/app start
fi
```

Note that this is still a very bad way to handle restarts of a service.  You should see if *app* maintains its own pid file, perhaps somewhere in /var/run/, then test the contents of that.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /var/run/app.pid ]; then
  if ps `cat /var/run/app.pid` >/dev/null; then
    /etc/init.d/app start
  fi
else
  /etc/init.d/app start
fi
```

Or even better, launch *app* using [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) or [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) or something equivalent that will take care of these things for you.

Comment: You crazily parse the pid out of `ps ax`, but the rest of what you say is excellent advice. (Hint: `ps ax -o pid=`, or at least `cut -f1 -d' '`.

Comment: Heh.  I don't like getting stuff from `ps ax` either, but there you go.  Re your suggestion, `cut -f1 -d' '` won't work because *space* is not the same as *whitespace*.  The ps column is right-justified if you include anything besides pid=.  That puts a single digit pid in field 5, a 2-digit pid in field 4, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The solution is to request minimum sizing for the `pid` column, like this: `ps ax -o pid:1=,comm=`.

Comment: That command line doesn't work for me.  It reports `ps: pid:1: keyword not found`.

Comment: What version of `ps`? I was presuming GNU for this.

Comment: Oh, I tried on both FreeBSD and Mac OS X.  Yay, another GNU difference.  :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `ps` this is easy and doesn't require any craziness.

```
if ! ps -C app >/dev/null ; then
     /etc/init.d/app start
fi
```

You just need to be careful that the `app` you pass to `ps` is the actual process name.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check on my servers right now, but Debian use [start-stop-daemon](http://man.he.net/man8/start-stop-daemon) to load services, it seems the right tool to use for your task, since it keeps track of your background process by PID and not just matching a name in the process list (which can do too).